# Twilio Conference statusCallback - PHP - statusCallback url never gets called on specified events

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm trying to log some data about ongoing conferences in my database by using conference statusCallbackEvent and statusCallback, however my statusCallback URL never gets called for the events specified in statusCallbackEvent.

For example, for an outgoing call I initiate the conference as such:

```
$response = new VoiceResponse();

$conferenceName = "agent_name";

$dial = $response->dial('');

$dial->conference(
    $conferenceName,
    [
        'startConferenceOnEnter' => True,
        'endConferenceOnExit' => True,
        'statusCallback' => 'https://my.url.com/conferenceCallback',
        'statusCallbackEvent' => 'start join end'
    ]
);
```

Then I add participants with:

```
$client->conferences($conferenceName)
    ->participants
    ->create()
```

I can see the events being triggered when I look at the Participant timeline in Insights, but the callback url is never called.

I'm using this doc as reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference

Really confused about why this is not working.

Comment: Your code looks fine, this is likely something you should take up with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). If you can provide Call Sids where you experienced this, they will be able to look into it for you.

Comment: @rdpqdev did the support help you? I have similar problem where status callback not firing no matter what but in messages, I wonder if they can help

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same issue, @AmirBar, twilio support wasn't much help but I figured it out.

Don't use "statusCallback" on $dial->conference, instead use "conferenceStatusCallback" and "conferenceStatusCallbackEvent" on the first participant resource like so:

*$client->conferences($conferenceName)->participants->create.*

This works for me. See doc here: [Conference Participant Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Which values for conferenceStatusCallback were you using?

Oddly if I set the statusCallback and statusCallbackevents as properties of the conference this worked, which was completely at odds with what the documentation says!!